# Different sensitivity and specificity for balanced populations

Tags: roc, sensitivity-specificity

I am building a simple test to flag prehistorical hand prints as belonging men or women.

Using a random variable built from the fingers lengths, and having measured a population, I built the ROC curve for which the Yunden's statistics identifies a point of maximal separation. For this point, the sensitivity of 20% and the specificity is 43%.
Here is then my question.

The sensitivity being here the probability for a population of real men to be flagged as men (symmetrically is the specificity for women), if I assume an initial population of 100 men and 100 women, I would then end with (20+57) flagged men and (80+43) flagged women. So the difference in sensitivity and specificity seems to bias my result.

Then
(1) Do I understand that correctly?
(2) How may correct this bias?